# The bounds of optimize.fminbound affect the results I'm looking for

Tags: python, optimization

The followings are my codes in Python:

```
import scipy.optimize as opt

q1=opt.fminbound(f, 0.00, 100.00, xtol=1e-9)
q2=opt.fminbound(f, 0.00, 1000.00, xtol=1e-9)
```

The result shows that q1 is NOT equal to q2, even though they are both in the interval (1.00, 10.00). What's the reason behind? How can I get the true optimal value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure but I'm guessing that the mathematical implementation of the algorithm that `fminbound` uses depends upon the range to find a stepsize. For your application it shouldn't really matter since you can specify an arbitrary xtol value.